# Awk printing specific variable & original data together between the pattern

Tags: design-patterns, awk, pattern-matching

[original data and desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oejRh.png)

Hello,

I want to get specific variable values between Patterns and print ( **REF_ID** value, **C_ID** value and **Date-Time** infront of it.

you can see Original data & Desired output below:

**input:**

```
[2018 13:50] ALI
REF_ID X 
A 3 
C_ID Y 
B 4 
[2018 14:00] ALI
C 3 
REF_ID Z 
D 1 
E 4 
C_ID T
```

**output needed:**

```
[2018 13:50] X Y [2018 13:50] ALI
[2018 13:50] X Y REF_ID X 
[2018 13:50] X Y A 3 
[2018 13:50] X Y C_ID Y 
[2018 13:50] X Y B 4 
[2018 14:00] Z T [2018 14:00] ALI
[2018 14:00] Z T C 3 
[2018 14:00] Z T REF_ID Z 
[2018 14:00] Z T D 1 
[2018 14:00] Z T E 4 
[2018 14:00] Z T C_ID T
```

I have tried the following but it does  not work as i desired.

```
awk '
BEGIN {FS=" "}
{if ($0 ~ /\[2018/) {flag=1;date_ref=$1;time_ref=$2;}            }
{if ($0 ~ /REF_ID/ ) {t_ref=$2}                   }
{if ($0 ~ /C_ID/ ) {gcid_ref=$2}        }
{if (flag=1) print date_ref,time_ref,t_ref,gcid_ref,$0}
'
```

output I got:

```
[2018 13:50]   [2018 13:50] ALI
[2018 13:50] X  REF_ID X 
[2018 13:50] X  A 3 
[2018 13:50] X Y C_ID Y 
[2018 13:50] X Y B 4 
[2018 14:00] X Y [2018 14:00] ALI
[2018 14:00] X Y C 3 
[2018 14:00] Z Y REF_ID Z 
[2018 14:00] Z Y D 1 
[2018 14:00] Z Y E 4 
[2018 14:00] Z T C_ID T
```

to solve the problem  i believe have to put the data to buffer  , collect the variable and merge it..

could you please help me to solve this problem? If you can explain the code you provide it would be much helpful.

Comment: those border lines are also part of input/output?

Comment: those border lines are not part of input/output. its simple space delimited  data

Comment: Agree with comments to clean up your sample data, but pluse-uno, as this is a much better than average first question. AND you have actually tried to solve your problem before posting. I would look into multi-line records in awk, and reference what you need as $3, $7, $9, etc. Good luck.

Comment: i have updated the post with the original raw data   and desired output for the testing.

Comment: @ Ed-Morton any comments?

Comment: I posted an answer. I think it's very clear and obvious what it's doing but post a comment under it if you have any question.

Comment: thanks for the answer , it works  smooth. Since  i am a beginner on awk ,could you please explain the code logic ? Especially the Associative array  parts.

Comment: OK I added a couple of comments to my answer. Btw remember to tag me with my name @EdMorton to be sure I see any comments you leave for me, I just came across this one by accident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
/^\[/ {
    prt()
    time = $1 FS $2
}
{
    map[$1] = $2     # save every 1st field to 2nd field mapping,
                     # e.g. map["REF_ID"]="X", map["C_ID"]="Y", etc.
    rec[++numLines] = $0
}
END { prt() }
function prt(   lineNr) {
    for (lineNr=1; lineNr<=numLines; lineNr++) {
        # now just retrieve the 2nd field values by their 1st field names
        print time, map["REF_ID"], map["C_ID"], rec[lineNr]
    }
    numLines = 0
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
[2018 13:50] X Y [2018 13:50] ALI
[2018 13:50] X Y REF_ID X
[2018 13:50] X Y A 3
[2018 13:50] X Y C_ID Y
[2018 13:50] X Y B 4
[2018 14:00] Z T [2018 14:00] ALI
[2018 14:00] Z T C 3
[2018 14:00] Z T REF_ID Z
[2018 14:00] Z T D 1
[2018 14:00] Z T E 4
[2018 14:00] Z T C_ID T
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you might be interested in this:

```
awk '($1 ~ /^\[/) && record { 
        string= date_ref OFS time_ref OFS t_ref OFS gcid_ref OFS
        gsub(ORS,ORS string, record)
        print string record 
        record=""
     }
    ($1 ~ /^\[/) { date_ref=$1; time_ref=$2 }
    ($1 == "REF_ID") { t_ref=$2 }
    ($1 == "C_ID")   { gcid_ref=$2 }
    { record = record ? record ORS $0 : $0 }
    END { string= date_ref OFS time_ref OFS t_ref OFS gcid_ref OFS
          gsub(ORS,ORS string, record)
          print string record 
    }' <file>
```

which outputs:

```
[2018 13:50] X Y [2018 13:50] ALI
[2018 13:50] X Y REF_ID X 
[2018 13:50] X Y A 3 
[2018 13:50] X Y C_ID Y 
[2018 13:50] X Y B 4 
[2018 14:00] Z T [2018 14:00] ALI
[2018 14:00] Z T C 3 
[2018 14:00] Z T REF_ID Z 
[2018 14:00] Z T D 1 
[2018 14:00] Z T E 4 
[2018 14:00] Z T C_ID T
```

The idea of the above code is to build a `record` into memory before printing anything. And while building the record, you pick relevant information such as `date_ref` `time_ref`, `t_ref` and  `gcid_ref`

1. `($1 ~ /^\[/) && record` When a record starts (denoted by a line starting with `[`) you have to perform actions on the previous record based on the information you picked. (unless its empty)

   1. `string= date_ref OFS time_ref OFS t_ref OFS gcid_ref OFS`: Build a `string` you want to place before each line (`OFS` is by default a space)
   2. `gsub(ORS,ORS string, record)` substitute all newline characters (default value of `ORS`) with `ORS string`
   3. `print string record` :: print the record with string in front of 
      it as the first line does not have the string in front of it yet.
   4. `record=""` reset `record`, as you build a new record from now on.
2. `($1 ~ /^\[/) { ... }`, `($1 == "REF_ID"){...}` and `($1 == "C_ID") { }` : extract the relevant information when the correct conditions are met (i.e. first field equals or matches the appropriate thing).
3. `{ record = record ? record ORS $0 : $0 }` Build the record by appending the current line to it with a newline in between (`ORS` is by default a newline character).  Note, you have to check if the record is empty in order not to have an extra `ORS` in the beginning.
4. `END` you still need to print the last record. Do all the actions from step 1 again.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not  work. after fixing the bracket [ character with  backslash  + bracket i got the output for  only the first block, second block did not show..

Comment: @DudeSkywalk fixed it!

Comment: @kvantour it works. If you dont mind could you please explain the code so i can understand how it works?

Comment: @DudeSkywalk explanation added

Comment: idk if it can happen but that will fail if there's an `&` in the parts of the input that constitute `string` due to `gsub(ORS,ORS string, record)`

Comment: @kvantour : I would like to thank you for your solution and effort. It gives me an edge on understanding awk. Thanks a lot.